# Existence of the limit $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}$$

I believe it does not exist because $x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$. Am I right?

Comment: Wait what is square root of x from the left?

Comment: @Lost1 Squeare root of x from the left does not exist, I believe.

Comment: Please make the titles for informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right but I have one minor nitpick. Since by definition you cannot compute the limit, I would say, rather, that the limit "cannot be computed" rather than "does not exist" since one does not imply the other.

Comment: Hmmm, while I would make the distinction as you do, in order to make sure we know what we mean in this case, one could also be doubly nitpicky right? Because $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists if $\exists l\in\mathbb R$ *such that*... etc. Certainly such an $l$ does not exist. Just playing the devil's advocate here

Comment: @GPerez Sorry, I don't fully understand your comment. Can you clarify a little?

Comment: Sure thing! Picking up from where I left off: $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists iff $\exists l\in\mathbb R : \forall\varepsilon > 0, \exists\delta : x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap\text{dom}f\Rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$ In this case, we say that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=l$  Here, $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\cap\text{dom}f=\phi$, so, in an (admittedly trivial) sense, no such $l$ exists, so one is justified in saying that the limit doesn't exist. If you haven't seen the limit definition I apologize (although that was it right there, nothing else to it!), feel free to ask any more questions :)

Comment: Ahh I understand now. I knew you were using the limit definition but didn't full understand why. Yea, you're right from a limit definition perspective that yes in fact the limit "does not exist" but again, you can't use the limit definition if the function is not defined in that scope. I guess, we're both kinda right here `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this limit does not exist because the $\ln{x}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ functions are not defined in $x<0$.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly $\ln x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ are undefined when $x<0$.  One could introduce "multiple-valued" versions of both of them (so that $\sqrt{x}=\pm\text{some imaginary number}$, etc.), but I would want to see that stated explicitly or else assume it was not intended.